# Weird behaviour of back propagation in a while_loop in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, while-loop, backpropagation

I am trying to see if Tensorflow can backpropagate through a while_loop without a pre-defined number of loops. Something weird caught my attention:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from numpy import *

tf.reset_default_graph()

X = tf.Variable(5.0, dtype = float32)
Y = tf.Variable(4.0, dtype = float32)

def cond(iterN, Y):
    return iterN<6

def body(iterN, X):
    return iterN+1, tf.add(X,X)
    # return iterN+1, tf.multiply(X,2)

finalOutX = tf.while_loop(cond, body, [0,X], parallel_iterations=1, back_prop=True, swap_memory=True)

gra = tf.gradients(finalOutX, X)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:

    init.run()
    X_val, graVal, = sess.run([finalOutX, gra])    

print(X_val)
print(graVal)
```

When the `body(iterN, X)` function returns `iterN+1`, `tf.add(X,X)`, I got an error stating

```
InvalidArgumentError: Retval[0] does not have value
```

However, when I replaced `tf.add(X,X)` by `tf.multiply(X,2)`, the code can be executed and return the correct answer `gra=64`.

Could anyone help me to understand where the error came from when I was using `tf.add(X,X)`? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like a weird TF bug. You could submit an issue [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues).

Comment: For those who care: change `tf.add(X,X)` to `tf.add(tf.multiply(X,1.0), tf.multiply(X,1.0))` is a dump workaround